ROS2 colcon build error MSB8066: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rosidl_generator_cs'
Using ros2cs, I am trying to build a package in Windows that includes a custom message type and eventually a service, for use in a C# solution aided by rclnet.  But executing this from the Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt (or regular command prompt) after executing my local_setup.bat fails:
C:\dev\SmplROS2dNET2>colcon build --packages-select svc_msg_pkg

The full event log file, minus timer events:
[0.000000] (svc_msg_pkg) JobQueued: {'identifier': 'svc_msg_pkg', 'dependencies': OrderedDict()}
[0.032000] (svc_msg_pkg) JobStarted: {'identifier': 'svc_msg_pkg'}
[2.485000] (svc_msg_pkg) JobProgress: {'identifier': 'svc_msg_pkg', 'progress': 'cmake'}
[2.500000] (svc_msg_pkg) JobProgress: {'identifier': 'svc_msg_pkg', 'progress': 'build'}
[2.500000] (svc_msg_pkg) Command: {'cmd': ['C:\\Program Files\\CMake\\bin\\cmake.EXE', '--build', 'C:\\dev\\SmplROS2dNET2\\build\\svc_msg_pkg', '--config', 'Release'], 'cwd': 'C:\\dev\\SmplROS2dNET2\\build\\svc_msg_pkg', 'env': {'ALLUSERSPROFILE': 'C:\\ProgramData', 'AMENT_PREFIX_PATH': 'C:\\dev\\ros2_humble\\ros2-windows;C:\\dev\\ROS2cs\\install', 'APPDATA': 'C:\\Users\\[myUserName]\\AppData\\Roaming', 'ChocolateyInstall': 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey', 'ChocolateyLastPathUpdate': '133538092742804663', 'CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH': 'C:\\dev\\ros2_humble\\ros2-windows;C:\\dev\\ROS2cs\\install', 'COLCON': '1', 'COLCON_PREFIX_PATH': 'C:\\dev\\ros2_humble\\ros2-windows\\', 'CommonProgramFiles': 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files', 'CommonProgramFiles(x86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files', 'CommonProgramW6432': 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files', 'COMPUTERNAME': 'USAPC408', 'ComSpec': 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe', 'DriverData': 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\DriverData', 'EFC_14916': '1', 'HOMEDRIVE': 'C:', 'HOMEPATH': '\\Users\\[myUserName]', 'LOCALAPPDATA': 'C:\\Users\\[myUserName]\\AppData\\Local', 'LOGONSERVER': '\\\\MAFAD01', 'MIL_Path': 'C:\\Program Files\\Matrox Imaging\\Mil\\DLL', 'MIL_Path64': 'C:\\Program Files\\Matrox Imaging\\Mil\\DLL', 'NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS': '12', 'OneDrive': 'C:\\Users\\[myUserName]\\OneDrive', 'OneDriveConsumer': 'C:\\Users\\[myUserName]\\OneDrive', 'OpenCV_DIR': 'C:\\opencv', 'OPENSSL_CONF': 'C:\\Program Files\\OpenSSL-Win64\\bin\\openssl.cfg', 'OS': 'Windows_NT', 'Path': 'C:\\dev\\ros2_humble\\ros2-windows\\opt\\yaml_cpp_vendor\\bin;C:\\dev\\ros2_humble\\ros2-windows\\opt\\rviz_ogre_vendor\\bin;C:\\dev\\ros2_humble\\ros2-windows\\opt\\rviz_assimp_vendor\\bin;C:\\dev\\ros2_humble\\ros2-windows\\opt\\libcurl_vendor\\bin;C:\\dev\\ros2_humble\\ros2-windows\\Scripts;C:\\dev\\ros2_humble\\ros2-windows\\bin;C:\\Python38\\Scripts\\;C:\\Python38\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VMware\\VMware Workstation\\bin\\;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NVIDIA Corporation\\PhysX\\Common;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Program Files\\Matrox Imaging\\Mil\\DLL;C:\\Program Files\\Matrox Imaging\\Tools;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\150\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\170\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\OpenSSL-Win64\\bin\\;C:\\opencv\\x64\\vc16\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\CMake\\bin;C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\cunit\\lib;C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\tinyxml2\\lib;C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\bullet\\lib;C:\\Program Files\\Graphviz\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Windows Performance Toolkit\\;C:\\Users\\[myUserName]\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\[myUserName]\\AppData\\Local\\GitHubDesktop\\bin;C:\\Users\\[myUserName]\\.dotnet\\tools', 'PATHEXT': '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW', 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH': 'C:\\dev\\ros2_humble\\ros2-windows\\lib\\pkgconfig', 'PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE': 'AMD64', 'PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER': 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 165 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel', 'PROCESSOR_LEVEL': '6', 'PROCESSOR_REVISION': 'a502', 'ProgramData': 'C:\\ProgramData', 'ProgramFiles': 'C:\\Program Files', 'ProgramFiles(x86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)', 'ProgramW6432': 'C:\\Program Files', 'PROMPT': '$P$G', 'PSModulePath': 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules', 'PUBLIC': 'C:\\Users\\Public', 'PYTHONPATH': 'C:\\ci\\ws\\install\\lib\\python3.8\\dist-packages;C:\\dev\\ros2_humble\\ros2-windows\\Lib\\site-packages;C:\\PROGRA~1\\MATROX~1\\MIL\\Scripting', 'Qt5_DIR': 'C:\\Qt\\Qt5.12.12\\5.12.12\\msvc2017_64', 'QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH': 'C:\\Qt\\Qt5.12.12\\5.12.12\\msvc2017_64\\plugins\\platforms', 'RMW_IMPLEMENTATION': 'rmw_fastrtps_cpp', 'ROS_DISTRO': 'humble', 'ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY': '0', 'ROS_PYTHON_VERSION': '3', 'ROS_VERSION': '2', 'SESSIONNAME': 'Console', 'SystemDrive': 'C:', 'SystemRoot': 'C:\\WINDOWS', 'TEMP': 'C:\\Users\\[myUserName]\\AppData\\Local\\Temp', 'TMP': 'C:\\Users\\[myUserName]\\AppData\\Local\\Temp', 'USERDNSDOMAIN': '[companyName].LOCAL', 'USERDOMAIN': '[companyName]', 'USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE': '[companyName]', 'USERNAME': '[myUserName]', 'USERPROFILE': 'C:\\Users\\[myUserName]', 'VS140COMNTOOLS': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\Tools\\', 'windir': 'C:\\WINDOWS', 'CL': '/MP'}, 'shell': False}
[3.250000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'MSBuild version 17.10.4+10fbfbf2e for .NET Framework\r\n'}
[3.438000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'\r\n'}
[4.282000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  1>Checking Build System\r\n'}
[5.235000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/SmplROS2dNET2/svc_msg_pkg/CMakeLists.txt\r\n'}
[7.000000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  running egg_info\r\n'}
[7.000000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  writing svc_msg_pkg.egg-info\\PKG-INFO\r\n'}
[7.016000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  writing dependency_links to svc_msg_pkg.egg-info\\dependency_links.txt\r\n'}
[7.016000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  writing top-level names to svc_msg_pkg.egg-info\\top_level.txt\r\n'}
[7.016000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b"  reading manifest file 'svc_msg_pkg.egg-info\\SOURCES.txt'\r\n"}
[7.032000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b"  writing manifest file 'svc_msg_pkg.egg-info\\SOURCES.txt'\r\n"}
[7.078000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/SmplROS2dNET2/svc_msg_pkg/CMakeLists.txt\r\n'}
[7.750000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/SmplROS2dNET2/svc_msg_pkg/CMakeLists.txt\r\n'}
[8.438000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/SmplROS2dNET2/svc_msg_pkg/CMakeLists.txt\r\n'}
[9.157000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'     Creating library C:/dev/SmplROS2dNET2/build/svc_msg_pkg/Release/svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_generator_c.lib and object C:/dev/SmplROS2dNET2/build/svc_msg_pkg/Release/svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_generator_c.exp\r\n'}
[10.094000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_generator_c.vcxproj -> C:\\dev\\SmplROS2dNET2\\build\\svc_msg_pkg\\Release\\svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_generator_c.dll\r\n'}
[10.438000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/SmplROS2dNET2/svc_msg_pkg/CMakeLists.txt\r\n'}
[10.813000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_c.vcxproj -> C:\\dev\\SmplROS2dNET2\\build\\svc_msg_pkg\\Release\\svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_c.dll\r\n'}
[11.125000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/SmplROS2dNET2/svc_msg_pkg/CMakeLists.txt\r\n'}
[11.735000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'     Creating library C:/dev/SmplROS2dNET2/build/svc_msg_pkg/Release/svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_cpp.lib and object C:/dev/SmplROS2dNET2/build/svc_msg_pkg/Release/svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_cpp.exp\r\n'}
[12.094000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_cpp.vcxproj -> C:\\dev\\SmplROS2dNET2\\build\\svc_msg_pkg\\Release\\svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_cpp.dll\r\n'}
[12.422000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/SmplROS2dNET2/svc_msg_pkg/CMakeLists.txt\r\n'}
[13.078000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'     Creating library C:/dev/SmplROS2dNET2/build/svc_msg_pkg/Release/svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c.lib and object C:/dev/SmplROS2dNET2/build/svc_msg_pkg/Release/svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c.exp\r\n'}
[13.375000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c.vcxproj -> C:\\dev\\SmplROS2dNET2\\build\\svc_msg_pkg\\Release\\svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c.dll\r\n'}
[13.719000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/SmplROS2dNET2/svc_msg_pkg/CMakeLists.txt\r\n'}
[14.391000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'     Creating library C:/dev/SmplROS2dNET2/build/svc_msg_pkg/Release/svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.lib and object C:/dev/SmplROS2dNET2/build/svc_msg_pkg/Release/svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.exp\r\n'}
[14.688000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.vcxproj -> C:\\dev\\SmplROS2dNET2\\build\\svc_msg_pkg\\Release\\svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.dll\r\n'}
[15.000000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/SmplROS2dNET2/svc_msg_pkg/CMakeLists.txt\r\n'}
[15.391000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_c.vcxproj -> C:\\dev\\SmplROS2dNET2\\build\\svc_msg_pkg\\Release\\svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_c.dll\r\n'}
[15.703000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/SmplROS2dNET2/svc_msg_pkg/CMakeLists.txt\r\n'}
[16.328000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'     Creating library C:/dev/SmplROS2dNET2/build/svc_msg_pkg/Release/svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp.lib and object C:/dev/SmplROS2dNET2/build/svc_msg_pkg/Release/svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp.exp\r\n'}
[16.625000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp.vcxproj -> C:\\dev\\SmplROS2dNET2\\build\\svc_msg_pkg\\Release\\svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp.dll\r\n'}
[16.922000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/SmplROS2dNET2/svc_msg_pkg/CMakeLists.txt\r\n'}

Most relevant part:
[17.657000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  Generating C# code for ROS interfaces\r\n'}
[17.875000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'  Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n'}
[17.875000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'    File "C:/dev/ROS2cs/install/lib/rosidl_generator_cs/rosidl_generator_cs", line 23, in <module>\r\n'}
[17.875000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b'      from rosidl_generator_cs import generate_cs\r\n'}
[17.875000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b"  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rosidl_generator_cs'\r\n"}
[17.922000] (svc_msg_pkg) StdoutLine: {'line': b"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Professional\\MSBuild\\Microsoft\\VC\\v170\\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(254,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'C:\\dev\\SmplROS2dNET2\\build\\svc_msg_pkg\\CMakeFiles\\9480f20c9281a3647441ac9328025e94\\setting_adjustment.cs.rule;C:\\dev\\SmplROS2dNET2\\build\\svc_msg_pkg\\CMakeFiles\\9399af840f193ffc6d3424eac4fbb3d9\\svc_msg_pkg__cs.rule;C:\\dev\\SmplROS2dNET2\\svc_msg_pkg\\CMakeLists.txt' exited with code 1. [C:\\dev\\SmplROS2dNET2\\build\\svc_msg_pkg\\svc_msg_pkg__cs.vcxproj]\r\n"}
[17.953000] (svc_msg_pkg) CommandEnded: {'returncode': 1}
[19.282000] (svc_msg_pkg) JobEnded: {'identifier': 'svc_msg_pkg', 'rc': 1}
[19.297000] (-) EventReactorShutdown: {}

My message file, SettingAdjustment.msg:
string adj_type
int16 new_setting

My package.xml:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>svc_msg_pkg</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>Package specifying </description>
  <maintainer email="me@company.com">username</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>rosidl_default_generators</build_depend>
  <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>
  <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>

My CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(svc_msg_pkg)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "Msg/SettingAdjustment.msg"
)

ament_export_dependencies(rosidl_default_runtime)
ament_package()

What files should I examine and modify first?  Thanks...
EDIT: my rosidl_generator_cs after the licensing comments:
import argparse
import os
import sys

try:
    from rosidl_generator_cs import generate_cs
except ImportError:
    # modifying sys.path and importing the .NET package with the same
    # name as this script does not work on Windows
    rosidl_generator_cs_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    rosidl_generator_cs_module = os.path.join(
        rosidl_generator_cs_root, 'rosidl_generator_cs', '__init__.py')
    if not os.path.exists(rosidl_generator_cs_module):
        raise
    from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

    loader = SourceFileLoader('rosidl_generator_cs', rosidl_generator_cs_module)
    rosidl_generator_cs = loader.load_module()
    generate_cs = rosidl_generator_cs.generate_cs


def main(argv=sys.argv[1:]):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Generate the CSharp ROS interfaces.')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--generator-arguments-file',
        required=True,
        help='The location of the file containing the generator arguments')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--typesupport-impls',
        required=True,
        help='All the available typesupport implementations')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--cs-build-tool',
        required=True,
        help='CS build tool to be used for compiling. Mono or DotNetCore')
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)

    return generate_cs(args.generator_arguments_file, args.typesupport_impls.split(';'), args.cs_build_tool)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```


Looks to me like you need to install rosidl_generator_cs? EDIT: nevermind you have it in your CMakeLists.txt.

Does C:/dev/ROS2cs/install/lib/rosidl_generator_cs/rosidl_generator_c actually contain the module? Could you check the path?
Could you delete the build-directory and rebuild?
I am unsure, since I never did some ros2 build on windows, but it looks like your building process uses python and loads the module there? Could you just import rosidl_generator_cs in some quick python-script?

@EricScöerg Please see my edit for the rosidl_generator_cs contents.  Is there a file to which I should add that import line?
